# error Trying to access array offset on value of type float

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this code:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://marine-api.open-meteo.com/v1/marine? 
latitude=10.307&longitude=-85.839&daily=wave_height_max,wind_wave_height_max&timezone=auto';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$array = json_decode($data, true);

echo "<table>";

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $value["time"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $value["wave_height_max"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $value["wind_wave_height_max"] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

and I am getting

> Trying to access array offset on value of type float

error

The JSON is:

```
{
    "latitude": 10.0,
    "longitude": -86.0,
    "generationtime_ms": 0.6439685821533203,
    "utc_offset_seconds": -21600,
    "timezone": "America/Costa_Rica",
    "timezone_abbreviation": "CST",
    "daily_units": {
        "time": "iso8601",
        "wave_height_max": "m",
        "wind_wave_height_max": "m"
    },
    "daily": {
        "time": ["2023-03-09", "2023-03-10", "2023-03-11", "2023-03-12", "2023-03-13", "2023-03-14", "2023-03-15"],
        "wave_height_max": [1.34, 1.14, 1.38, 1.70, 1.84, 1.72, 1.72],
        "wind_wave_height_max": [0.14, 0.26, 0.16, 0.40, 0.74, 0.22, 0.10]
    }
}
```

Comment: The first item of the resulting array, that you are looping over, has the key `latitude` and the value `10.0`. Trying to access `$value["time"]` of course makes no sense with that value.

Comment: Well you've got a single object there, not an array...so you can't loop it the way you're expecting. Looks like you actually wanted to loop the "daily" values, but that's not an array either, it's an object which contains a set of separate arrays.

Comment: Have a read of [How to extract and access data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-to-extract-and-access-data-from-json-with-php) and then make sure you understand what the JSON you're looking at there actually represents. If you find it easier to read PHP array syntax, then run `var_export($array);` after you've created it, so you understand the structure you're dealing with.

Comment: @ADyson, Mariano has always been calling `json_decode($data, true)` -- this will be creating arrays, not objects.  The json encoded format, of course, looks like objects.

Comment: @mickmackusa indeed. my comment referred to the JSON structure, not the resulting php variable, probably should have made that clearer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should update your code to access `wave_height_max` and `wind_wave_height_max` values from the `daily` :

```php
<?php
$url = 'https://marine-api.open-meteo.com/v1/marine?latitude=10.307&longitude=-85.839&daily=wave_height_max,wind_wave_height_max&timezone=auto';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$array = json_decode($data, true);

echo "<table>";

foreach($array["daily"]["time"] as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $array["daily"]["wave_height_max"][$key] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $array["daily"]["wind_wave_height_max"][$key] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```